# Panel fullscreen fails on exit using trigger('resize')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize

I have a popup window that automatically goes into fullscreen.

I also have a button to exit fullscreen and a button to exit(close), if the window is fullscreen the exit button works perfectly, but if it is not in fullscreen the button to exit bugs the whole page.

How can I fix this?

**Code:**

```
`$(document).ready(function () {
        var count = 1 ;
        $(".dr" + count).parents('.panel').toggleClass('fullscreen');
        $(window).trigger('resize');
    });
    document.getElementById("detalhes" + count).outerHTML = '';
}`
```

**EDIT:**
PHP Remove from code.

Comment: **Don't** mix PHP and JS.

Comment: @AksenP, done, it was a test, sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirm if is in fullsceem or not:

```js
var count = 1 ;
 if ($(".dr" + count).parents('.panel').hasClass('fullscreen')) {
  //its in fullscream so trigger fullscreen again then remove

     $(document).ready(function () {
   $(".dr" + count).parents('.panel').toggleClass('fullscreen');
   $(window).trigger('resize');
  });
  document.getElementById("detalhes" + count).outerHTML = '';
   }else{´
  //isn't in fullscreen so just remove
  document.getElementById("detalhes" + count).outerHTML = '';
  
   }
```